# Two definitions for a smooth curve equal.

Tags: derivatives, plane-curves

I've encountered these two definitions:
1. $\gamma\colon [a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ is smooth if all three derivatives exist and $\gamma^{\prime}(t) \neq 0 \;\; \forall t \in [a,b]$

1. $\gamma\colon [a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ is smooth if all three derivatives exist and are continuous.

why they are equivalent?

I mean that why curve has a tangent  at each point if the second condition exists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "equivalent", not "equal"... (Not  an answer; just a nitpick with your terminology.)

Comment: What do you mean by $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$, I'm not seeing what that would indicate if it were false.

Comment: "smooth" in many cases means $C^\infty$, if this is the case, then both definitions are wrong.

Comment: @EnjoysMath that may be to ensure the function is an immersion (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_%28mathematics%29 )

Comment: In many Differential Geometry's book the condition $\gamma'(t)\neq0, \forall t\in\mathbb{R}$ is the definition of "regular" curves, hence the definition depends of the book you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions are not equivalent. Yes, if you impose the condition that $\gamma'(t)\ne 0$ for all $t$, you'll have a non-zero tangent vector, and hence a tangent line, at each point. For differential geometry, one wants this condition—so that one can reparametrize by arclength, for example.

If you consider $\gamma(t)=(t^2,t^3)$, you see that the curve is a cusp and does not have (classically speaking) a tangent line at $t=0$. Nevertheless, this fits the second definition.

Comment: but the curve (t^3,t^3) is the same curve as(t,t) and (t,t) has a tangent line at t=0.

Comment: @Victor: Its image is set-theoretically the same, but not the same as a parametrized curve.